# Split every other vector element and stack into matrix or dataframe

Tags: r, split

I have elements pairs where I need to split every second element into multiple comma-delimited elements and stack them into two dimensions with the first element repeated as many times as necessary:

```
v <- c("Cha, Seungman", "1,2", "Jin, Yan", "3")
```

(The numbers of element pairs and comma-delimited elements can be above 2.)

I need:

```
     [,1]            [,2] 
[1,] "Cha, Seungman" "1"
[2,] "Cha, Seungman" "2"
[3,] "Jin, Yan"      "3"
```

(Data frame output also good.)

Comment: `data.frame(matrix(v,2,byrow = T))%>%separate_rows(X2)`

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, split(v, c("nm", "val")))) %>%
    separate_rows("val", sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, you can use vector recycling to select alternate elements. Split the number on comma (`,`) and `cbind` them.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, v[c(TRUE, FALSE)], strsplit(v[c(FALSE, TRUE)], ",")))

#     [,1]            [,2]
#[1,] "Cha, Seungman" "1" 
#[2,] "Cha, Seungman" "2" 
#[3,] "Jin, Yan"      "3"
```